# Postgres Additional Join increases sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-models

```
SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN "token"."name" = ''  THEN 5 ELSE 9 END) AS "n"
FROM "word"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "token" ON ("word"."id" = "token"."word_id")
where ("word"."id" = 1)
GROUP BY "word"."id";
```

This gives expected result of 14 as there is exactly one empty and one non-empty token.

```
SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN "token"."name" = ''  THEN 5 ELSE 9 END) AS "n"
FROM "word"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "token" ON ("word"."id" = "token"."word_id")
INNER JOIN "token" T3 ON ("word"."id" = T3."word_id")
where ("word"."id" = 1)
GROUP BY "word"."id";
```

This query outputs `n=28`, which is 14 doubled.

Why is that?

Comment: You can't have '*' and GROUP BY. It's meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

This is your revised query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN t."name" = ''  THEN 5 ELSE 9 END) AS "n"
FROM "word" w LEFT OUTER JOIN
     "token" t
     ON w."id" = t."word_id" INNER JOIN
     "token" T3
     ON w."id" = T3."word_id"
WHERE w."id" = 1
GROUP BY w."id";
```

It makes no sense.  You are joining the same column in `word` to the same column in `token` -- twice.  The reason you are getting duplicates is because you have multiple rows in `token` for a given word.  You can easily check this:

```
select word_id, count(*)
from token
group by word_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

However, your query makes no sense.  I might suggest that you ask *another* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want the query to do.

Comment: Why doesn't it makes sense? I join the token table with itself.

Comment: @AndrewFount . . . The two joins are on the same keys on the same underlying tables.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Why is there a difference if I write  SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN "token"."name" = ''  THEN 5 ELSE 9 END) AS "n" FROM "word" LEFT OUTER JOIN "token" ON ("word"."id" = "token"."word_id") INNER JOIN "token" T3 ON ("token"."id" = T3."id") where ("word"."id" = 1) GROUP BY "word"."id";

Comment: @AndrewFount . . . Yes, but that also doesn't make much sense.  Why would you be doing a self-join on the `id` column in a table.  I suggest you ask another question with sample data, desired results and an explanation of what you are trying to do.